# java.lang.IllegalStateException using retrofit

Tags: java, android

i get an error on my application when i run it that says :

**com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $**

but i dont know how to fix it , even though i saw some solutions for this error but didnt know where to edit or how , can you help me ?

here's my retrofit part wit server response :

```
   Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL).client(client).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build();

    final RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
    User user = new User();
    user.setEmail(ProfileFragment.Global.email);
    final ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
    request.setOperation("check");
    request.setUser(user);



    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            Call<ServerResponse2> response1 = requestInterface.check( ProfileFragment.Global.email );

            response1.enqueue( new Callback<ServerResponse2>() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse2> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse2> response1) {

                                      ServerResponse2 resp = response1.body();



                                          Toast.makeText( BService.this, resp.getResult() , LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                                      Toast.makeText( BService.this, ProfileFragment.Global.ID , LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                                      Toast.makeText( BService.this, ProfileFragment.Global.Mylat , LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                                      Toast.makeText( BService.this, ProfileFragment.Global.Mylong , LENGTH_LONG ).show();





                                      if (resp.getResult().contains( "true" ))
                                      {


                                          Call<ServerResponse2> response2 = requestInterface.track( "123456"  , ProfileFragment.Global.Mylong, ProfileFragment.Global.Mylong, "56" );

                                          response2.enqueue( new Callback<ServerResponse2>() {
                                              @Override
                                              public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse2> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse2> response2) {

                                                  ServerResponse2 resp = response2.body();
```

**my interface :**

```
@GET("project5/web/")
Call<ServerResponse2> check(@Query("email") String email );
@GET("project5/web/track/")
Call<ServerResponse2> track(@Query("id") String id,@Query("long") String longg, @Query("lat") String lat  , @Query("battery") String battery);
```

Comment: Show your ServerResponse2 class

Comment: post your ServerResponse2 and your json response

Comment: public class ServerResponse2 {

    private String result;
    private String islost;
    private User user;

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return islost;
    }



}

Comment: i posted my serverresponse2 class in the previous comment @shmakova

Comment: i posted my serverresponse2 class in the previous comments @BhuvaneshBs